# How to enable Material You icon for Android for my MAUI app?

Tags: android, maui, material-you

I want those icons that change the background and foreground color based on your Material You color scheme. How do I do this?

Playing around with the default .NET 7 app.

I tried changing `AndroidManifest.xml` to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

I also tried manually creating an `ic_launcher.xml` in the `Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a little bit more research I have found [icon.kitchen](https://icon.kitchen/). Where once you generate your icon, download them, and extract the `res` folder into your `Android\Resources` folder it works.

I hope this can help save people research time!